# roundToDecimals returns too many digits

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I have a process which returns a floating point number. Then I use the `roundToDecimals` method to eliminate some digits.

```
roundToDecimals(weight,3)
```

----update june 22 2012 : 1.42 am----

```
public static double roundToDecimals(double d, int c) {
int temp=(int)((d*Math.pow(10,c)));
return (((double)temp)/Math.pow(10,c));
}
```

---end of update

It works well but returns more than 3 digits after the decimal point if the last digit is zero
ex

```
0.0020
0.0060
0.333
0.071
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?  That you don't like the appearance of the 0 after the last non-zero digit?  Please include the code you use to print the values.

Comment: the problems is solved guys.

the value is not printed but but write it in a text will and will be read by svmlight. and svmlight always returns error if found more than 3 digit after koma. 

the problem was i run my java code and the program concurrently, if i stop my java apps then run svmlight it works.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your 0.333 case. There *is* no binary floating point (`double`, `float`) representation which is *exactly* 0.333. There's just "the closest value to 0.333" which is what you'd get if you used

```
double d = 0.333;
```

(I'm assuming you're complaining about the result of your `roundToDecimals` method, which I assume is a `float` or `double`. It's hard to tell from your question.)

Comment: it returns variable in double
 

really need suggestion, im new in java

Comment: @HermanPlaniGinting: Well it sounds like you need to learn about floating point numbers to start with... there are lots of articles around about how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Your method cannot possibly work. You can't round a floating-point value to a specific number of decimal places, because a floating-point value doesn't *have* decimal places. It has binary places. If you want decimal places you have to convert to a decimal radix, e.g. via `DecimalFormat` or `BigDecimal`.